# Python If / Else statement not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

```
input1 = raw_input("").lower()
if input1 == "no":
    print "no"
if input1 == "yes":
    print "yes"
else:
    print "nothing"
```

This is a simplified version of a problem I'm having, I know why it's happening but don't know how to fix it, or what to look for. Every time anything other than the last if statement is ran it always prints the `else` along with it.

Example: If I put 'no' into this, it prints 'no' and 'nothing', but if 'yes' is entered it only prints 'yes'.

Comment: Use `elif`. Just read out your conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two separate if statements in there.  So the code will check if input1 is equal to "no", and then it will check if it is equal to "yes" every time.  If you change it to this:

```
  input1 = raw_input("").lower()
  if input1 == "no":
    print "no"
  elif input1 == "yes":
    print "yes"
  else:
    print "nothing"
```

Then it will be one statement that will first check for 'no', if that is false, it will check for 'yes', and finally, if that is false, it will print 'nothing'.

Answer (score 1):

You have one `if` separated from an `if/else`; the first test can pass, and the second test is still performed (with the `else` condition executing if it fails). Change the test to:

```
if input1 == "no":
    print "no"
elif input1 == "yes":  # <-- Changed if to elif so if input1 == "no" we don't get here
    print "yes"
else:
    print "nothing"
```

The English description of your original code is "If input1 equals 'no', then print 'no'. If input1 equals 'yes', print 'yes', but if it's not equal 'yes', print 'nothing'." Note how the two sentences are disconnected; whether or not you print `nothing` is independent of the test for `no`.

Side-note: You could simplify this code a bit:

```
if input1 in ("no", "yes"):
    print input1
else:
    print "nothing"
```

which avoids the problem entirely (of course, your real code is likely more complex, so you couldn't use this trick).

Answer (score 0):

You have two `if` conditions. The second should be an [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements). Change your

```
if input1 == "yes":
```

to

```
elif input1 == "yes":
```